# Ошибки с calc в вёрстке (LESS)

Tags: less

Высота элемента div зависит от высоты родительского элемента:

```
.leg_content {
    overflow: auto;
    height: calc(100% - 51px);
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 43px;
}
```

В [примере jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ju0ks7pw/10/) работает как надо. В приложении div сжимается до половины формы по высоте. Если открыть вёрстку элемента в браузере, там `height: calc(49%);`
Если изменить вручную в консоли браузера на `height: calc(100% - 51px);` , то элемент располагается как нужно.

**Обновление:** в примере jsfiddle есть ещё один calc: `max-height: calc(100% - 120px);`, и он в приложении тоже не работает - форма просто не отображается, если эту строчку раскомментировать (если я правильно понимаю, то высота считается отрицательной и обнуляется).

В чём может быть проблема? Браузер Chrome, версия актуальная.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильный синтаксис:

```
height: ~"calc(100% - 51px)";
height: calc(~"100% - 51px");
```

Таким образом LESS не будет пытатся его вычислить.